# Guardar fechas con horas con formato 12 horas en mongo con c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

Es que tengo una fecha pero al momento de guardarla `mongoDb` me pone la hora de la fecha en formato 24 horas u horario militar.

Ejemplo:

La fecha es esta `{6/04/2017 3:03:00 p. m.}` y me la guarda así `{2017-04-06 15:03:00.000}`

¿que hago para guardarlo en el formato como llega?

Answer (score 1):

Vas a tener que cambiar la configuración del servidor con respecto al formato de fecha/hora.

Para hacerlo más simple, te recomiendo cambiar en la capa de presentación.

Si estás haciendo desarrollo web, ve con la librería [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // October 12th 2018, 10:27:00 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Friday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Oct 12th 18
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2018 escaped 2018
moment().format();                          // 2018-10-12T10:27:00-07:00
```

Si estás con C#

```
// Display using current (en-us) culture's short date format
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2008, 3, 15);
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d"));           // Displays 3/15/2008
```

Aquí puedes encontrar mayores detalles:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings